# Manually turning volume with knob on speakers makes audio clip on computer

Tags: sound

When I manually change the volume on my Bose desktop speakers using the volume knob, the volume in Pulse Audio goes above 100% and everything starts clipping. Is there a way to stop this happening?

Running Lubuntu 16.04.

Comment: How are the speakers connected? 3.5mm speaker-out socket or USB? It seems very odd if changing hardware volume on external speakers changes the software volume setting.

Comment: Joe - The speakers are connected with 3.5mm, I agree, it was an odd problem. That computer died of old age, and getting a new one solved the problem. Thanks for taking the time to reply.